# Permutar linhas de uma matriz em Python 3

Tags: python, lista, matriz, combinações

Como posso fazer uma permutação em uma matriz em Python 3?
Por exemplo, tenho a seguinte matriz 3x3:

```
matriz = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
]
```

Gostaria de permutar não os termos dentro dela, mas sim as linhas.

Tenho que fazer um código que me permita gerar todas as permutações possíveis arranjando os pares de linhas dessa matriz (que são 6 [3!]) como os pares:

- `([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])`
- `([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])`
- `([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9])`
- ... e por aí vai.

Preciso disso para calcular equações lineares. O que encontrei até agora foram códigos que fazem permutações **dentro** de uma lista com os termos que estão dentro dela. Estou totalmente perdido, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Uma matriz é uma lista de listas, ou seja, uma lista na qual cada elemento é outra lista. Sendo assim, a forma de obter as permutações dos seus elementos é exatamente a mesma, pois para o algoritmo não importa o que cada elemento da lista é (poderiam ser números, strings, ou qualquer outra coisa (inclusive outras listas), a forma de permutar não muda). Então basta usar o código que vc já encontrou e aplicar na sua matriz. Se não deu certo, seria bom [edit] a pergunta e colocar o código que tentou e o erro que deu.

Comment: Na verdade, eu estou atrás de uma luz pra saber como começar. Tenho um trabalho em que tenho que pegar uma matriz dada pelo user e tenho que fazer o método de eliminação de Gauss pra calcular o sistema de equações dela. A permutação é apenas uma das etapas para eliminar qualquer chance de existir uma equação igual dentro da matriz sabe?

Answer (score 1):

Se você está fazendo isso como um exercício ou lição, talvez não possa aplicar o código a seguir. Mas de forma bem prática, é possível usar `itertools.permutations(seq, n)` para obter todas as permutações dos elementos de `seq`, agrupados em `n` elementos.

Como sua matriz é efetivamente uma *sequência de linhas*, é só passá-la para a função e pedir para permutar os seus elementos (= linhas), agrupando-os de 2 a 2. Por exemplo:

```
from itertools import permutations

matriz = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
]

for p in permutations(matriz, 2):
    print(p)

# output:
# ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
# ([1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9])
# ([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3])
# ([4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
# ([7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3])
# ([7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: `*map(print, permutations(matriz, 2)),`

Comment: Poxa ja ajudou pra caramba!! Muito obrigado!